# How to swap generated mesh based on camera distance (geometry nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make a procedural forest in geometry nodes and I ran into performances issues. So I tried to make an LOD system. Problem is: I generate my trees procedurally and I want to swap the mesh for a pre-made billboard tree based on the camera distance. I haven't found a way to make the switch node work, since I don't have access to the original point position of the tree distribution once I generated the trees. I don't think I can swap meshes at instancing either, since I do multiple operation on the mesh after instancing. How should i go about his?
Here's a mock-up of my node tree (it's to big to fit on a screenshot, so this is a simplified verison):
[image]

Answer (score 3):

By using `Instance Index` of `Instance on Points` node you can set different objects to the points.
This setup shows basic culling based on distance from the camera.
[image]
(Note that objects naming should be in increasing order of its subdiv levels)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatly, this doen't work for me, as I need to modify the basic scatered mesh to make the trees, so swapping them for billboard trees would just make a mess as the operations would be performed on the billboard tree mesh and not on the generated mesh. I need to be able to either swap meshes after applying the operations, or swap the meshes before and find a way to stop the operations to happen after scattering.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. May be you can use instance to points node after doing the operations. It would be easier to look if you share the file.